# Is there a PHP equivalent to Compass?

Tags: php, css, compass-sass

From my understanding, [Compass](http://compass-style.org/) only works with Ruby. Is there a PHP equivalent to Compass?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Compass actually works great for PHP projects. I've used it on several CakePHP and Symfony projects. Compass is *built* with Ruby, so you need Ruby on your machine, but it compiles to plain old CSS. If you have Ruby (and RubyGems) installed, just install the Compass gem and you should be ready to go. Earlier versions of Compass used a Ruby-style syntax, but my understanding is that later versions have adopted a more CSS-like option.

If you haven't already, start with the [documentation where installation is discussed](http://compass-style.org/docs/) in more detail.

Comment: Yes, it is ruby as compile time dependency, but not as runtime dependency. Ruby projects can actually skip the compilation by making its web framework compile things as needed (several plugins are provided for Sinatra, Rails and others.)

Comment: I am working on Compass Extensions to support Drupal, since i find them both to work out really great. Just compile before uploading.

Comment: Let me get this straight. You need ruby as compile-time dependency to initially get the compass framework installed into the project (and to add extensions, etc...) but you don't need it on the production server? I would prefer to remove ruby as a requirement on the production server if possible (on the development server it doesn't really matter).

Comment: Evan: that is correct. The SASS code is compiled to plain old CSS, so just deploy the css files and there's no need for Ruby on any upstream servers.

Answer (score 3):

PHAMLP is a php port of Sass and Compass:

http://code.google.com/p/phamlp/ or https://github.com/bluelovers/PHamlP

PHPSass is a port of PHamlP up-to-date with the v3.1.1.5 specification of SASS:

http://www.phpsass.com/ or https://github.com/richthegeek/phpsass